# node watch folder doesn't trigger callback if changes are made by a demon

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, daemon

As wrote in title, I have a daemon that moves a file into a nodejs watched folder. When this move happens, callback is not called.
Both daemon and watcher, runs as root.

If I manually `touch` a file or if I do a `mv/cp` into this folder, all works great. It seems that the daemon does something different. Any idea of why this happens?

I'll solve in a different way, but I want to understand why of this strange situation.

- File system: ext4
- SO: debian 7
- Uname output: Linux smsgw-pre 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux
- NodeJS: 10.31

I'm using node `fs.watch` for this.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is being used for watching the folder? Perhaps some demo code would be beneficial.

Comment: Some indication of what the daemon is doing would also be important.

Comment: As I wrote, daemon is moving files from a folder to another one I'm watching with node API `fs.watch`. Nothing else.